# my transaction shows as reverted but i didn't recieved my money yet

Tags: transactions, ether, bsc, bscscan

So I transfered some Binance-Peg Ethereum Token (ETH) over the bnb network (bsc20) (with my ledger wallet/app), but the status of the transaction shows 'reverted'
There are some articles saying that 'no transaction is done and your money should be in your wallet'
But now, the money is neither on my or the reciever wallet.
Any suggestions?
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb2448ce56c104a248483b1284ce5e461874e2574ddd96a549fd761e2aa6208af

Comment: Nothing gets taken when a transaction reverts. That shows as successful on bscscan (https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb2448ce56c104a248483b1284ce5e461874e2574ddd96a549fd761e2aa6208af). Binance pegged eth was sent to 0x2b5d76da98d219957b65f1d65a6881965b52f379 then to 0xE56fE0c32FC63A45f9d6cdf4AEBdAa1228B9EE02.

Comment: Just contacted the support of nobitex.ir (the wallet that I transfered to) and they fixed it just in time. Thank you all for the help. @Maka

Comment: That is wonderful, all the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a transaction to send value or make *any* state changes, it must succeed.
If part of a transaction fails, then the entire [transaction reverts](https://ethereum.org/en/whitepaper/#ethereum-state-transition-function) and all of the value sent is returned to the sender, except for the gas fee.

In your case, the transaction didn't `revert` like you thought it did but instead successfuly transferred `.06073652` "*Binance-Peg Ethereum*" to `0x2b5D76DA98D219957B65f1d65a6881965B52f379`.

[image]

Then `0x2b5D76DA98D219957B65f1d65a6881965B52f379` called the contract `0xf466f27fB811Ab1572CA67ab438E966910f5d9C1`'s `create_child_with_token()` function and sent the entire `0.06073652` to `0xE56fE0c32FC63A45f9d6cdf4AEBdAa1228B9EE02`.

[image]

You can view this second transaction [here](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe85c6d549c7c482434b5d9736ae7d4269f17000558f80ad9c79dddb583616300).

Comment: Just contacted the support of nobitex.ir (the wallet that I transfered to) and they fixed it just in time. Thank you all for the help.